# $system_path for EE setup in subdirectory

Tags: php, focus-lab-master-config

I need to move an EE install into a subdirectory. The site currently has the system folder above web root and uses focus lab's dynamic config setup.

My desired setup would this:

```
--system
--config
--public_html
   |
   |-my_subdirectory
      |
      | -assets
      | -index.php
      | -admin.php
         etc.
```

However I could not get the index.php working as yet. Anyone having an idea what the correct value for the $system_path variable located in the index.php would be?

Many Thanks

Comment: You can give the full server path here like

    `$system_path = '[SERVER PATH]/system';`

Answer (score 3):

The solution involved the following steps:

1. set the $system_path in the index.php and admin.php to $system_path = '../../system';
2. change a couple of lines in the config.master.php:

   on line 93 add your directory name to the $base_url variable like so:

   $base_url = $protocol . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/my_subdirectory';

   on line 94 add your directory name to the $base_path variable like so:

   $base_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_subdirectory';
3. in case you use absolute path for your links in the site you will also have to do a find and replace for your href tags.